# jQuery hide div on mouseout

Tags: jquery, html

I saw a lot of posts on this item, but couldn't find the right solution. Sorry if it's already answered somewhere.

**What I want:**
I have a `DIV` with my menu items, that opens when the `click` event is fired of an `href` element.
Now I wanna hide the menu, when the mouse is out of the `DIV` element and is not above the `href` element. So far I can only close it when I click the `href` element.

So, my jQuery looks like this:

```
$("#menu_opener").click(function () {
            if ($("#menudiv").is(":hidden")) {
                $("#menudiv").slideDown("slow");
            } else {
                $("#menudiv").hide();
            }
        });
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
<a href="#" id="menu_opener">Menu</a>
</div>
<div id="menudiv" style="position: fixed; background-color: white; display: none;">
    <a href="#" id="A1">Page 1</a><br />
        <a href="#" id="A2">Page 2</a><br /> 
    <a href="#" id="A3">Page 3</a><br />                           
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18):

You can keep the HTML as is and  simply add the following:

```
$("#menudiv").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5SSDz/**

Comment: Good answer, but its a bit buggy. When you roll over the word Test and then move your mouse to the right, then back over Test, then down - there are some odd behaviours. I don't know how to fix it, just letting you know its a little buggy.

Comment: @JaydenLawson I would recommend you do this using CSS, instead of javascript. My experience with mouse events has been that they are not 100% reliable. You can use some CSS3 transition effects.  I'm sure you can find something on Google, I'm not a CSS guy, so can't help with the css code.

Answer (score 6):

if i understand the "is not above the href element" piece, you want the menu to stay visible when mousing off of div#menudiv, but still moused over a#menu_opener ??

if that's the case, i'd wrap the entire thing in a unqiue div and target that.
and use mouseleave over mouseout.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

so, your HTML becomes:

```
<div id="menu_container">
  <div>
    <a href="#" id="menu_opener">Menu</a>
  </div>
  <div id="menudiv" style="position: fixed; background-color: white; display: none;">
    <a href="#" id="A1">Page 1</a><br />
    <a href="#" id="A2">Page 2</a><br /> 
    <a href="#" id="A3">Page 3</a><br />                           
  </div>
</div>
```

and your script would be something like:

```
$("#menu_opener").click(function () {
  if ($("#menudiv").is(":hidden")) {
      $("#menudiv").slideDown("slow");
  } else {
      $("#menudiv").hide();
  }
});
$("#menu_container").mouseleave(function(){
    $('#menudiv').hide();
});
```

Comment: With some extra CSS for the positioning this solution works perfect!

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Sorry misread the question the first time. I had to do this a couple of times, and I always moved the menu a pixel up so that it would overlap the href element. And then show/hide the menu if the href OR href elements are being hovered.

```
$("#menu_opener, #menudiv").hover(
    function(){
        $("#menudiv").show();
    },
    function(){
        $("#menudiv").hide();
    }
);
```

And set the top property for the menudiv's style so it moves up and is overlapping the href.

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="menu_opener">Menu</a>
</div>
<div id="menudiv" style="position: fixed; top: -1px; background-color: white; display: none;">
    <a href="#" id="A1">Page 1</a><br />
    <a href="#" id="A2">Page 2</a><br /> 
    <a href="#" id="A3">Page 3</a><br />                           
</div>
```