# jquery hide a div if mouse leaves it or calling span

Tags: jquery, hide, mouseout

**edit**

I am still un-able to get this working....

I have tried the code below and while it works on the page it dose not work on the divs and spans I want it to work on...

if you go to [2hon5.net](http://2hon5.net) you can see the code working it displays the pop ups via the code at [2hon5.net/js/2hon5.js](http://2hon5.net/js/2hon5.js):

```
 $("#wordInf").css({'display':'block'});
```

(It is hidden by default)
You can see all the code I have been trying there too, can any one see what in my code is stopping the pop up from disappearing?

**End edit**

I have tryed a number of solutions including this one: [similar question I couldn't get working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616407/jquery-hide-div-on-mouseout) I have an info pop up which displays dynamic info depending on which span it hovers over. I have it set so it will pop up directly below the current span. I want it to disappear after a small delay if the calling span or the div itself is no longer being hovered over (as it has links in it). I have had zero luck, any suggestions?

```
<span onmouseover='callHover(code1234,this)' class='code 1234'>The calling span</span>
<span onmouseover='callHover(code1235,this)' class='code 1235'>The calling span</span>
```

The called div is:

```
<div id="codeInf" >
<span id="code_id">generated code here</span>
<a href="#">link 1</a>
<a href="#">link 2</a>
<a href="#">link 3</a>
<a href="#">link 4</a>
</div >
```

The jquery to call the div is:

```
$("#codeInf").mouseover(showCode);
var showCode = function(ev) {
  var pos = $("#codeInf").offset();  
  var width = $("#codeInf").width();

  $("#codeInf").css( { "left": (pos.left + width) + "px", "top":pos.top + "px" } );
  $("#codeInf").show();
}
```

I tried the code in the questioned linked to above but it dose not work - maybe because of the way I am calling my code?

The result I want is code that will hide the code if the calling span OR the codeInf div are no longer being hovered over, the one div can be called to many different spans so I don't want the delayed hide to affect it if it has been called by another span.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the jQuery's [hover documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

example:

```
$("li").hover(function () {
    // focus
}, function () {
    // lost focus
});
```

Comment: I tried this code but got no reaction, what did I do wrong? I left the hover blank as the pop up already works... $("codeInf").hover(function () {
    // focus
}, function () {
    $('#codeInf').hide();
});

Answer (score 1):

Simple thing is to add mouseleave to both the span and the popup's div.

```
      $("span").hover(function() {
          // hide all other divs
          $("div").slideDown("slow");
      });

      function hidepanel() {
          if ($('div').is(':hover') === false) {
              $('div').slideUp(); 
          }
      }

      $('div').mouseleave(function() { setTimeout(hidepanel, 4000); });
      $('span').mouseleave(function() { setTimeout(hidepanel, 4000); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8CRVX/

Comment: +1 - exactly what i've been looking for... Just the right amount of code!

Answer (score 1):

It is not a perfect result but I solved the issue by adding a  onmouseout'hideChar()' to the calling and generated div.

Thin I did a bool to set the divs to hover or not:

```
var isWordHover=new Boolean(0);
var isCharHover=new Boolean(0);

function charHover2(){
isCharHover=Boolean(1);
setTimeout(HC, 4000);
}
```

The I set it to make the value 0 on mouseout and 1 on mouse over. Need to work out some bugs (sometimes it dose not pick up the mouse out etc... But it hides the pop up and gives the ability to hover over and click the links.

Thanks for the advice all.

Mark