# Hide dropdown div with jQuery on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know there are hundreds of topics regarding this, however none of them seemed to work for me. I want for the dropdown to hide when the mouse leaves the element with jQuery, this is what I currently get:

[image: Example of current undesired behavior]

**[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/valik140795/pen/qadXOo)**.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.expand').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('section').slideUp('normal');
    if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') === true) {
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    }
  });
  $('section').hide();
});

$('section').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

I've also tried the following:

```
$('section').hide();
$('.section').on('mouseout',function(){
    $(this).hide();
})
```

Yet, nothing really seems to work correctly and gives me the same result. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you give us your html code?

Comment: I see you have both `section` (tag) and `.section` (class) in your js file. Is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: Guess this is you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6616698/4323328

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: @utaco not exactly, I've already tried this method and it never worked for me (you can see thats what i already use in the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woaQzv)**.

You should use `setTimeout()/clearTimeout()` functions to solve your problem so you've to attach `mouseleave` event to the button with class `dropbtn` and both `mouseleave/mouseleave` events (using `hover()`) to the div `dropdown-content` so when the mouse leave the button to any other element you should check if the `mouseenter` is inside the dropdown, if yes clear the timeout the `hide_dropdown` so it will not hide the div, else your time out will hide the dropdown after 50ms :

var hide_dropdown;

```
$('.dropbtn').mouseleave(function(e){
    var _this = $(this);
    hide_dropdown = setTimeout(function(){
        _this.next('.dropdown-content').removeClass('show');   
    },50);
});

$('.dropdown-content').hover(
    function(){
        clearTimeout(hide_dropdown);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('show');
    }
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you check your codepen link, it actually doesn't work (for me at least), the menu pops up and permanently hides. Moreover, if you attempt to click it again, it just does drop down at all again ever. How i see it: https://gyazo.com/c532e5cca98990fd248a7817528a0b8b. Thanks for help though.

Comment: Now I'm unable to click the items in the menu. https://gyazo.com/4fb009877c37fe068220eb9d0b011176

Thank you so much for even helping thus far!

Comment: Updated my answer with new approach using `setTimeout()/clearTimeout()` functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127650/discussion-between-valbone-and-zakaria-acharki).

Answer (score 0):

you code it's confusing so i made a simple example for what you want.

see here snippet >

```js
$(".dropbtn").click(function(){
           var showMe = $(this).siblings(".drop-menu"),
               visibleDrop = $(this).parent("li").siblings("li").find(".drop-menu").filter(":visible")
           $(showMe).slideDown()
           $(visibleDrop).slideUp()
      $(showMe).mouseleave(function(){
             $(this).slideUp()
     })
})
```

```css
ul { list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}
ul li { display:inline-block;width:20%;position:Relative}
ul ul li { display:block;}
ul ul  { display:none;position:absolute;top:100%;left:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a class="dropbtn"> Has Children1</a>
     <ul class="drop-menu">
     <li>SubItem1</li>
      <li>SubItem2</li>
       <li>SubItem3</li>
     </ul>
</li>
<li><a class="dropbtn"> Has Children2</a>
     <ul class="drop-menu">
     <li>SubItem1</li>
      <li>SubItem2</li>
       <li>SubItem3</li>
     </ul>
</li>
<li><a>No children</a></li>
<li><a> No children</a></li>
</ul>
```

or fiddle > **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lc7do5g/2/)**

let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<a href="#" id="menu_opener">Menu</a>
</div>
<div id="menudiv" style="position: fixed; background-color: white; display: none;">
    <a href="#" id="A1">Page 1</a><br />
        <a href="#" id="A2">Page 2</a><br /> 
    <a href="#" id="A3">Page 3</a><br />                           
</div>
```

link:-http://jsfiddle.net/5SSDz/

Answer (score 0):

In your codepen example, I have added the following code snippet inside ready callback which seems to work.

```
$('.expand').on("mouseleave", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('section').slideUp('normal');
});
```

Here is the complete js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.dropbtn').on("mouseleave", function(e){
   $(".dropdown-content").removeClass("show");

});
$('.expand').on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('section').slideUp('normal');
if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') === true) {
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
}
});
$('section').hide();
});
```

Comment: @P Praveen, updated codepen: http://codepen.io/valik140795/pen/qadXOo

Not working that well - in fact doesn't do anything differently from what it used to. Thanks for effort though.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 
   $('.dropbtn').on("mouseleave", function(e){
   $(".dropdown-content").removeClass("show");
 
});
$('.expand').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('section').slideUp('normal');
    if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') === true) {
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    }
});
$('section').hide();
});

Comment: Thank you. Same issue as @Zakaria though - https://gyazo.com/4fb009877c37fe068220eb9d0b011176

Comment: I will come up with a css solution shortly

Comment: Thank you very much, however Im not sure I will be capable to implement it without completely destroying the current structure of the website - I'm a complete novice and it will simply require for me to recode the whole website because of one button if you do this in css. Im fairly unexperienced and could be wrong though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127648/discussion-between-p-praveen-and-valbone).